# ipv6 support on AWS in Elastic Beanstalk on US East (N. Virginia)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS. I have PHP web service and hosted on AWS.

I have created elastic beanstalk on US East (N. Virginia) and i got default URL from AWS. I checked that URL on  http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php but it is showing "This website is not ready for IPv6" . I want ipv6 support for the AWS.

Please provide step by step guidance .

Answer (score 4):

AWS doesn't support IPv6 on EC2.  You could do it with a Classic loadbalancer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html

Comment: This is wild, why on earth would this be the case, and still over a year later: no solution!

Comment: Coming back to this, somehow I find my own comment: it's now 3 years. Wild.

Comment: It's now 2023, and this is no longer accurate. See e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/ipv6/, or this article https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-configure-with-ipv6

Answer (score 2):

In June'18, IPv6 is supported by EC2 (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ipv6-support-for-ec2-instances-in-virtual-private-clouds/). But it depends of the region where your instance are.

A simple pattern, as suggested by a colleague, would be to create an IPv6 dedicated VPC, with public access and all Subnets with IPv6 enabled. Create an Application Load Balancer in this VPC to redirect traffic to the Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer. Trafic from IPV6 LB to EBS LB will be in ipv4.

Or you can recreate a complete VPC with IPV6 enabled, also on all subnets with correct routing tables. Then create a Beanstalk env with Application LB. When created, change the ALB settings to enable "dualstack ip", change security group to allow trafic from IPV6 (::/0) and wait a few minutes for all DNS name and SG to be completely changed.

Comment: It's supported but what url can you use in the DNS record? Ones of this form `http://ENV_NAME.pimtefdfsg.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` (where pimtefdfsg is some id that aws gives) which work for A records don't seem to work for AAAA.

Comment: Do you know how to have trafic from LB to EC2 in IPv6?